# Python Install Cerfiticates Command

Tags: python, url, https, pycharm, python-3.9

I'm fairly new at Python and I'm trying to execute some code, and from what I can read, it has something to do with reading HTTPS.

I get this error:

```
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)>
```

Online I can see that I should run the Install Certificates command in my Python folder, but when I do, I get the following error:

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/certifi'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

Then I've read that I could execute following command:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

But when I do, it says that the command does not exist.

I'm at loss on what to do. I'm on a Mac, using Python 3.7 in PyCharm.

Hope someone can help :-)

/************/

Update:

I have installed Python 3.7 and was now able to run the Install Certificates command, but I still get the first error when I run my code :-(

Comment: Don't call `pip` directly. Instead use `path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip install certifi` for example. -- https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Comment: You probably can update your Python or system in general (maybe that would help solve the old SSL certificates). -- Then you probably use _virtual environment_, so that you can have fresh `certifi` in there without having to mess with the libraries of the globally-installed Python.

Comment: I installed Python 3.9 and now I could successfully run the Install Certificates command. However when I run my code I still get following error: 

urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)>

Comment: What is the code that you are running? What command are you calling?

Comment: I'm trying to use PyTube3  :-)